# Send button on Long press gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

how can send button name, tag or text in long press gesture? I need to know the button name that long presed on.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [button setTagS:[[ToalData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:4]];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(siteButtonPressed:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    ///For long//
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self
                                               action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    [button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    ////


    NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[ToalData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1]];
    [button setTitle:string1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(XLocatioan, YLocation, 90, 30);

    [self.view addSubview:button];


(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender
{

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");

}
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");




       }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every gesture recognizer is attached to a ["`view`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/view), which is a property on the gesture recognizer.

So in your "`handleLongPress`" method, you can do something like:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender.view;

NSLog(@"title is %@", button.titleLabel.text);
NSLog(@"tag is %d", button.tag);
```